# Pull Price Bar for Specific Time

Tags: pine-script

While there is lots of documentation online for calculating the time difference (unix time) between price bars, does anyone know if it is possible to pull a price bar (OHLC data) for a specific time.

E.g. My strategy is running in 15sec resolution and the current bar is 14:30:15. time - 86400 is 24hrs earlier, is is possible to pull the price bar (or specifically, the close price) for: time-86400? I'm trying to determine if the price now is higher/lower than it was 24hrs earlier.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more efficient way to do this, but it does work. Place all the timestamps in an array and remove any older than 24hrs. Results in the last element of the array being 24hrs ago. Since each timestamp is added each bar, we can determine the bar_index from the array size.

```
f_prune24H(_timestamps, _current_bar_time) =>
    _size = array.size(_timestamps)
    _24ts = int(_current_bar_time - 86400000)
    for _i = _size - 1 to 0
        if array.get(_timestamps, _i) < _24ts
            array.remove(_timestamps, _i)
        _last_index = array.size(_timestamps) - 1
        if _last_index > 0 and array.get(_timestamps, _last_index) >= _24ts
            break
    _timestamps
    
var int[] timestamps = array.new_int(na)

array.unshift(timestamps, time)

temp_timestamps = f_prune24H(timestamps, time)

timestamps := temp_timestamps

high_24h = high[array.size(timestamps) - 1]

plot(high_24h)
```